# How to request background location permission, but fall back to when in use permission in iOS / React Native?

Tags: ios, react-native, geolocation, beacon

So what I would need to do is one of the following:

a) When the app launches, first ask for background location permissions. If the user declines, ask if we can use foreground location.

b) When the app launches, ask for foreground location permissions. Later, the user would be able to go to their settings page, and enable background location tracking if they wish.

The problem I've run into, is that if I ask for background location permissions, I am unable to ask for foreground location permissions after the user declines. I want to allow users to choose the level of location tracking, instead of having a all or nothing type deal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**One common approach is to ask the user with your own dialog first.**  Only request the system permission if the user agrees to grant from your dialog.

If the user declines your dialog, you can then ask for the foreground permission with your own dialog, and if the user agrees to that request it from the system.

**EDIT:** As of iOS 13 this process has changed.  See [here](http://www.davidgyoungtech.com/2019/10/18/permission-denied) for details.